# C# Set Windows Folder View

Tags: c#, browser, controls, settings, directory

I'd like to change the view of a specific folder via code.  For example, on my computer, my default preference is to view all folders in a list, sorted by type and display the name, date modified, type and size columns.  What I'd like to do is to change one specific folder to view small icons and file name only.

The reason behind this is I have a web browser control pointing at a shared directory in one of my applications.  I want the UI to be consistent from user to user, so is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is saved in the registry.

Check this out: [How to modify your folder view settings or to customize a folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812003)

In the troubleshooting section:

> By default, Windows XP and Windows
>   Server 2003 remember each folder's
>   view settings and customizations. This
>   data is limited to 400 folders and is
>   stored in the following registry keys:
>
> **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell**
>
> **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam**
>
> Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008
>   instead use the following registry key
>   to store this information:
>
> **HKCU\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell**